# VBA userform with options named from variable

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to make a sort of hot/not program with boys names for our comming child in Excel VBA.

I have now programmed VBA to pick two random names from a large list. Now the user should be asked which of the two names, the user likes best. For example:

Excel chooses `Adam` and `Brian` from a long list. `Adam` is stored in `variable name_1` and `Brian` is stored in `variable name_2`.

Now I want some kind of dialog box with three options:

1. The content of Name_1 (Adam)
2. The content of Name_2 (Brian)
3. A Cancel button which terminates the running macro.

I have tried to make a userform, but I cannot name the buttons with the contents of the variables. Is that possible, and if so, how?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Most of the objects on userform have `.Caption` property if you set it right you should be able to assign variables to any objects like button, label, etc... Eg. like `Button1.Caption = strvariable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example form:

[image: User Form]

I have named the buttons **btn1** and **btn2**.

If you single click on a button and have a look at the properties panel you will see an entry for **Caption**:

[image: Caption property]

The **caption** property is available for you to use at runtime. For example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    btn1.Caption = "Andrew"
    btn2.Caption = "Rachel"
End Sub
```

When you run the above you get:

[image: Form results]

So just use the **caption** property and you should be sorted!